# How can I use recursion to repeat a string?

Tags: python, recursion

i've been stuck on a question for some time now:

I'm looking to create a python function that consumes a string and a positive integer. The function will print the string n times, for n lines. I **cannot** use loops, i must only use recursion

e.g.

```
>>> repeat("hello", 3)
hellohellohello
hellohellohello
hellohellohello
```

whenever i try to make a function that does this, the function decreases the length of the string, progressively:

e.g.

```
>>> repeat("hello", 3)
hellohellohello
hellohello
hello
```

here's what my code looks like:

```
def repeat(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        print(a*n)
    else:
        print(a*n)
        repeat(a, n-1)
```

What is wrong with this attempt? How can I fix it?

Comment: So, you are confused what the `n-1` is doing?

Comment: yes, i want to keep the number of times the string is printed in one line as a fixed sort of parameter, but i want the function to repeat the line n times.

Comment: Hint: you can modify the first argument to `repeat` the same way you modify the second. Instead of passing `n` on the recursive call, you pass `n-1`. So instead of passing `a`, maybe pass something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
def f(string, n, c=0):
    if c < n:
        print(string * n)
        f(string, n, c=c + 1)

f('abc', 3)
```

Comment: I like the trick of counting up so you can use a default `0` for the 3rd parameter.

Comment: this is great and easy to understand! thank you! the count up is a great way to approach it

Answer (score 7):

One liner

```
def repeat(a,n):
    print((((a*n)+'\n')*n)[:-1])
```

Let's split this up

1. `a*n`  repeats string `n` times, which is what you want in one line
2. `+'\n'` adds a new line to the string so that you can go to the next line
3. `*n` because you need to repeat it `n` times
4. the `[:-1]` is to remove the last `\n` as `print` puts a new-line by default.

Comment: Doesn't use recursion, though

Comment: I assumed "use recursion if needed"

Comment: @zyxue I explained the steps. You can always have temporary variables for the steps.

Answer (score 4):

So you just need extra argument that will tell you how many times you already ran that function, and it should have default value, because in first place function must take two arguments(`str` and positive number).

```
def repeat(a, n, already_ran=0):
    if n == 0:
        print(a*(n+already_ran))
    else:
        print(a*(n+already_ran))
        repeat(a, n-1, already_ran+1)
repeat('help', 3)
```

Output

```
helphelphelp
helphelphelp
helphelphelp
helphelphelp
```

Answer (score 2):

You were really close.

```
def repeat(a, n):
    def rep(a, c):
        if c > 0:
            print(a)
            rep(a, c - 1)
    return rep(a * n, n)
print(repeat('ala', 2))
alaala
alaala
```

A function with closure would do the job.

Comment: super close, i'm looking to print (a*n) n times

Comment: No idea why this is upvoted when it literally does the same thing as the OP's method.

Comment: Usually, it's better to avoid nested function unless you have a very strong argument for it. It's also harder to test. In this case, I can see the motivation, an advantage of this solution over a 3-argument function is that it eliminates the possibility of mistakenly passing 3 arguments. You can make `rep` a bit cleaner by changing the condition to `if c > 0`, then you don't need to write a single-line return statement

Comment: @zyxue yes, it might be better idea to change the statement as you said. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You should (optionally) pass a 3rd parameter that handles the decrementing of how many lines are left:

```
def repeat(string, times, lines_left=None):
    print(string * times)

    if(lines_left is None):
        lines_left = times
    lines_left = lines_left - 1

    if(lines_left > 0):
        repeat(string, times, lines_left)
```

Comment: This could be reduced, but I wanted to be verbose for its self-explanatory nature.

Comment: camelCase is not very pythonic.

Comment: Ugh, thank you @zyxue! It's been a while since I've been in Python...forgot about that one.